# List of pair in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have an arraylist of Pairs -

```
public static ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> fields;
```

From my controller, I render this list to view using

```
return ok(index.render(fields));
```

Now in index.scala.html , I have

```
@(fields : List[(String,String)])
```

But this gives me compilation error that types dont match.
Are pairs not supported in scala? Or should I use some other syntax to achieve this?

Is there a compatible type in Scala for Java Pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is due to type mismatch. It expects `scala.collection.immutable.List[(String,String)]` but instead you are passing `java.util.List[(String,String)]`.

To solve it do:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
return ok(index.render(fields.asScala.toList));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `fields` value is of type `java.util.ArrayList`, but the parameter expected by index.scala.html is a `scala.collection.immutable.List` - hence the type mismatch.

Comment: When I pass an ArrayList<String> to view and receive it as List[String], then it works fine. I think the problem is with Pair. Is there a compatible type of Pair in scala?

Comment: @user2694377 Hmm, OK - where is the `Pair` type in your `fields` declaration coming from, then? There is a type class `Pair` defined in scala.Predef (which is automatically imported in Scala for you) that equates to Tuple2 - are you using this, or something else (maybe defined as a Java class/interface)?

Answer (score 0):

try below in index.scala.html:

```
@import java.util
@(fields : util.List[(String,String)])
```